# Factor in ultraproduct

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

> The general method for getting ultraproducts uses an index set I, a structure $M_i$ for each element i of I (all of the same signature), and an ultrafilter U on I. The usual choice is for I to be infinite and U to contain all cofinite subsets of I. Otherwise the ultrafilter is principal, and the ultraproduct is isomorphic to one of the factors. (ultraproduct, Wikipedia)

What does "factor" refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the six lines that immediately follow the sentence that you quoted. You start with an indexed family $\{M_i:i\in I\}$ of structures of the same type (linear orders, rings, fields, etc. $-$ technically, they have the same *signature*). You form the Cartesian product $$M=\prod_{i\in I}M_i\;;$$ the structures $M_i$ are the factors of this product. You take an ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ on $I$, and you use it to define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $M$:

$$\langle m_i:i\in I\rangle\sim\langle m'_i:i\in I\rangle\text{ iff }\{i\in I:m_i=m'_i\}\in\mathscr{U}\;.$$ The ultraproduct of the $M_i$ is the quotient $M/\sim$, often written $M/\mathscr{U}$, whose elements are the $\sim$-equivalence clases. Although $M/\sim$ is no longer strictly speaking a product, we still speak of the $M_i$ $-$ the genuine factors of the Cartesian product $M$ $-$ as its *factors*.